# Axios making a request from HTTPS to HTTP source

Tags: firebase, http, https, axios, hosting

I have a running Azure java backend service which is without a security certificate and a running Firebase Hosting React project with a security certification.

Backend: **http://** some_ip_address:10000/

Frontend: **https://** project_id.web.app/

I am using **axios** in the frontend project. When I make an axios request, I am facing to this **Mixed-Content** error.

`Mixed Content: The page at 'https://project_id.web.app/auth/login' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure XMLHttpRequest endpoint 'http://some_ip_address:10000/otp/create'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.`

Instead of changing "insecure content" setting from the browser, what is the solution to fix this?

Comment: hi, experiencing the same issue :( were you able to solve it ?

Comment: We had to add ssl certificate to backend as well.. @jmvcollaborator